# How to test an angular service with a call to subscribe in it?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, rxjs, jasmine, observable

I have a service called `page.service.ts`. I want to test its `loadPage(path: string)` method. But I cannot execute the `subscribe` block from the spec file. When I run the test I see `load Page called` printed to the console but `Subscribe is being executed` is never printed.

Please see the service file and spec files below:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Page } from '../models/page.model';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';
import { BehaviorSubject, Observable } from 'rxjs';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class PageService {

  public currentPath: string;
  public page = new BehaviorSubject<Page>(null);

  constructor(private http: HttpClient) {}

  public loadPage(path: string) {
    this.currentPath = path;
    console.log('load Page called');
    const request_url = environment.apiBaseURL + 'api/structure/page/';
    console.log(request_url);
    const request = this.http.get(request_url,  {
      params: {
        path: this.currentPath + '/'
      }
    });

    request.subscribe(
      (results: any) => {
        console.log('Subscribe is being executed');
        const p = new Page().deserialize(results);
        p.path = path;

        this.page.next(p);
      }
    );
  }

  isActivePage(page: Page) {
    return this.currentPath === page.path;
  }
}
```

spec file:

```
import { TestBed, fakeAsync, flush, tick } from '@angular/core/testing';

import { PageService } from './page.service';
import { HttpClientTestingModule, HttpTestingController } from '../../../node_modules/@angular/common/http/testing';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import PAGES  from './mock-data/page.service.mock.spec';

fdescribe('PageService', () => {
  let pageSrv: PageService,
    httpTestingController: HttpTestingController;

  beforeEach(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [HttpClientTestingModule],
      providers: [
        PageService
      ]
    });

    pageSrv = TestBed.get(PageService);
    httpTestingController = TestBed.get(HttpTestingController);
  });

  it('should be created', () => {
    const service: PageService = TestBed.get(PageService);
    expect(service).toBeTruthy();
  });

  fit('should load page', fakeAsync(() => {
    const r = PAGES.NewsItem1
    pageSrv.loadPage('/news-announcements/article/announcement/');
    // flush();
    tick(5000);
    const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(environment.apiBaseURL + 'api/structure/page/');
    console.log('running expect');
    expect(req.request.method).toEqual("GET");

    req.flush({r});
  }));
});
```

Answer (score 1):

One option is to *not* subscribe in the service.

You could instead subscribe in the component OR use a more declarative, stream-based approach:

**product.service.ts**

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {
  private productsUrl = 'api/products';

  // All products
  products$ = this.http.get<Product[]>(this.productsUrl)
    .pipe(
      tap(data => console.log('Products', JSON.stringify(data))),
      catchError(this.handleError)
    );
}
```

Also, here is a great post providing two choices for testing Observables:

https://blog.angularindepth.com/how-to-test-observables-a00038c7faad

Lastly, I have not tried this, but you may be able to use:

```
it('should...', async(async() => { } ))
```

There is an example here: https://netbasal.com/testing-observables-in-angular-a2dbbfaf5329, but it is testing a component with a subscribe, not a service.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with DeborahK that subscribing in the service in general is not a good idea.  However, this may be code you have been asked to write tests for but you can't modify, or you simply desire to code it this way, so to answer your question directly all you are likely missing is the fact that you have added query params to your URL inside your service method, but you aren't accounting for that in the expect statement:

```
const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(environment.apiBaseURL + 'api/structure/page/');
```

I have put together a working [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/stackoverflow-q-58493997?file=app%2Fpage.service.spec.ts) to show your test now passing and the subscribe being called.  Here is the full `fit()` from that StackBlitz:

```
fit('should load page', () => { // <--- do not need fakeAsync
  const r = PAGES.NewsItem1
  pageSrv.loadPage('/news-announcements/article/announcement/');
  // flush();
  // tick(5000);  // <--- This is not needed

  // build up the total expected URL including the query parameter added:
  const expectedURL = `${environment.apiBaseURL}api/structure/page/?path=/news-announcements/article/announcement//`

  const req = httpTestingController.expectOne(expectedURL);
  console.log('running expect');
  expect(req.request.method).toEqual("GET");
  req.flush({r});
});
```